# POSIX REGEX vs PCRE

Tags: posix

I have this expression that checks for a valid email address.
This is from https://www.regexpal.com/19 and it works fine.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$
```

TEST string: `hello@yahoo.com`.

Testing this with POSIX returns an error. I would like to know what part of that is invalid with POSIX.

Comment: In POSIX BRE (basic regular expressions) there is no `+` for "one or more".

Answer (score 1):

POSIX specifies two types of regular expressions,

1. Basic Regular Expressions, BRE
2. Extended Regular Expressions, ERE

We need to know which you want to use.

The most obvious incompatibilities with PCRE are lack of `+`, `{n,m}` and `(?...)` in BRE, and `(?...)` in ERE. Please study the [Opengroup's BRE and ERE Specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09) for details.